# How can I use map! in julia?

Tags: julia, vectorization

How can I use `map!` with a function using vector variables in julia?

Codes below did not work.

Perhaps, there might be a simple solution of below codes,

but I want to use `map!` in this problem.

```
 a1 = ones(100, 2)
 a2 = ones(100, 2)
 a3 = ones(100, 2)

 function expe1(v1,v2,v3)
  v1 + v2 + v3
 end

 dest = [zeros(100) for i in 1:2]

 map!(expe1, dest, eachcol(a1), eachcol(a2), eachcol(a3))
```

Error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching map!(::typeof(expe1), ::Vector{Vector{Float64}}, ::Base.Generator{Base.OneTo{Int64}, Base.var"#242#243"{Matrix{Float64}}}, ::Base.Generator{Base.OneTo{Int64}, Base.var"#242#243"{Matrix{Float64}}}, ::Base.Generator{Base.OneTo{Int64}, Base.var"#242#243"{Matrix{Float64}}})
Closest candidates are:
  map!(::F, ::AbstractArray, ::AbstractArray) where F at abstractarray.jl:2924
  map!(::F, ::AbstractArray, ::AbstractArray, ::AbstractArray) where F at abstractarray.jl:2967
  map!(::F, ::AbstractArray, ::AbstractArray...) where F at abstractarray.jl:3024
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[8]:1
```

Comment: Please always report expected results and error you get when posting a question like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method of `map!` for non-array iterables, because it insists on all arguments being `AbstractArray`s having the same shape.

To write the result into a destination array without intermediate allocation, you could broadcast-assign it a generator:

```
julia> dest .= Base.Generator(expe1, eachcol(a1), eachcol(a2), eachcol(a3))
2-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0  …  3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
 [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0  …  3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

Something like this should also work:

```
function my_map!(f::F, dest::AbstractArray, As...) where F
    for (i, a...) in zip(eachindex(dest), As...)
        val = f(a...)
        @inbounds dest[i] = val
    end
    return dest
end
```

Comment: Maybe there should be a `map!` version for non-array iterables? Perhaps limiting the arguments to be LinearIndex-able and filling up to length of `dest`? It felt weird that `map` and `map!` diverge in behaviour perhaps unnecessarily.

Comment: I also felt that it is slightly inconsistent. I have added a possible implementation based on the `map!` methods.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps, `map!` type functions are not compatible with non-array iterables. It helps me.

Answer (score 2):

Please check with latest Julia, it works fine with Julia 1.9.0-DEV:

```
map!(expe1, dest, eachcol(a1), eachcol(a2), eachcol(a3))
2-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0  …  3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
 [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0  …  3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]

julia> VERSION
v"1.9.0-DEV.1332"
```

And you could just do:

```
expe1(eachcol(a1), eachcol(a2), eachcol(a3))
2-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0  …  3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
 [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0  …  3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: Cool, I'll try it with the new version of Julia

Comment: That is an "accident", though: in 1.9, `eachcol` returns a `Slices` object, which is an `AbstractArray` (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/32310). `map!` still doesn't work on iterators in general.